# Android: how know from where user open application google play store link

Tags: android, algorithm, google-play, ads

I have an application, which advertise it in many sites, and every site have it's own unique referral key which I gave them .
when user open the application link in google play store and install the app , I want to know from which referral site user navigate to store and install my app.
dose Google Play Store has any API for this? if no how can I handle it?
I don't want to use google ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google have the sdk for doing this.
[Referrer Document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer)